# vector count function C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a vector

```
vector<int> vec;
```

it's storing random numbers {5, 7, 8, 9, 13, 15, 17}

and I have a vector that is evaluating the previous vector's numbers as 1 or 0 if they are a prime number or not

```
vector< int> vec_prime_number;
```

so for the previous it would be {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}

I'm trying to use the count function to save only the prime numbers in it. And I'm having some problems with doing it.

Ideally, I would like to make it so that vec has
{5, 7, 13, 17} //in other words, only prime numbers in it

I've tried stuff like

```
int cnt = count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec_prime_number())
```

but I can't get any of it to work. Any ideas on how to get count to store only the prime numbers?

Comment: `vec_prime_number` isn't a function, you shouldn't put `()` after it.

Comment: "but I can't get any of it to work." what does that mean ? Did your computer rebel and try to kill you ?

Comment: I tried int cnt = count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec_prime_number) and that still is not working.

Comment: `count` looks for exact matches, it doesn't search a vector for matches.

Comment: And what does counting have to do with what you're trying to do, anyway? Just write a loop that goes through `vec_prime_number`. If the element is 1, push the corresponding element of `vec` onto the result vector.

Answer (score 7):

The documentation of `std::count` says:

> Returns the number of elements in the range [first,last) that compare equal to val.

so you should use something along the lines of the following, to get the number of prime numbers:

```
int cnt = count(vec_prime_number.begin(), vec_prime_number.end(), 1);
```

as [you can see](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48254394e8870c9c).

Answer (score 2):

*"Ideally, I would like to make it so that `vec` has {5, 7, 13, 17} //in other words, only prime numbers in it"*

You don't need to count simply use :

```
bool IsPrime (int i) 
{ 
  /*returns true, if i is Prime */
}

vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), IsPrime), vec.end());
```