# remove_if, getting the opposite bool c++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have the code

```
vector <int> v;

v.erase(remove_if(v.begin(),v.end(),bool_checker),v.end());
```

where `v` is a vector that is holding random numbers `{2, 4 ,5, 6, 7, 11}` and `bool_checker` is a class object that evaluates whether the number is prime or not

I want to erase the numbers that are not prime numbers. In other words, I want `v` to look like `{5, 7, 11}`. Right now `v.erase()` is erasing not prime numbers. so the output is `{2, 4, 6}`.

I can't get the compiler to accept the not of `bool_checker`. I've tried `(!bool_checker)`, `bool_checker==false`, etc. and none of these have worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like this is extension of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19106925/1870232) :D

Comment: Since bool_checker is an object, what does it mean to negate it?  You're not passing a boolean value to remove_if, but an object, at the time of passing the arguments, there is no true/false value to negate, but the arguments must be evaluated before they are passed.

Comment: @Arunas: The negation of a boolean predicate is a predicate that returns the negated result.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: wild, I would not have expected that to work, nor can I convince g++ 4.6.3 to expect it to work.  for example `a.erase(remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(), odd), a.end());` will compile, but `a.erase(remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(), !odd), a.end());` does not, nor does `a.erase(remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(), ![](int x) { return (x % 2) != 0;}), a.end());` (though it will without the `!`.  As far as I can tell, `std::not1()` is not the same a `!`.  Did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: @Arunas: Yes, you misunderstood. I didn't say that you could use `!` to negate a predicate; just that the concept of the negation of a predicate is well defined.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: ah good, so we were both misunderstood.  I'll try to make my comments clearer in the future.  thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
v.erase(remove_if(v.begin(),v.end(),std::not1(bool_checker)),v.end());
```

Comment: When I tried this, I'm getting /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:210:4: error: no match for call to '(                                                                                              std::unary_negate<isprime>) (int&)'
 error about 6 times. This might have something to do with my boolean function is a class object. Any idea why I am getting that error?

Comment: @Mdjon26: That's because `not1` requires the predicate to define an `argument_type` type (as you should see from the earlier errors). Unless you're stuck in the past, it's more convenient to use a lambda instead.

Comment: `std::not1()` is deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20. From C++17 you can use [`std::not_fn()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn) instead - or just use a lambda

Answer (score 4):

You can use a lambda to return the negation of the return value:

```
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [] (int x) {
    return !bool_checker(x);
}), v.end());
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, 2 is a prime number.

Second, without seeing the contents of `bool_checker`, it sounds like your logic is backwards inside it.  A simple version (not efficient) might look like:

```
bool bool_checker(int i)
{
    int root = (int)sqrt(i);
    for (int j = 2; j <= root; ++j)
    {
        if (i % j == 0)
        {
            return false; // number is not prime
        }
    }
    return true; // number is prime
}
```

If you cannot, or do not want, to change your `bool_checker` functor, you can negate it:

```
v.erase(remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::not1(bool_checker)), v.end());
```

Comment: I tried the second part of the v.erase and I'm getting the error I mentioned above. Any ideas?

Comment: What does your `bool_checker` look like?